# Are questions that ask for Christian's evaluation of a specific cult's view of love, etc. on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Occasionally I see cults promoting teachings on topics that are central to Christianity such as this Japanese [Happy Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Science) promoting [four stages of love](https://happy-science.org/ryuho-okawa/teachings/) that on the surface has a lot of similarities with Christianity's progression of natural-love --> Agape love --> Unitive love (in mysticism).  [The founder](https://happy-science.org/ryuho-okawa/) even commissioned [an autobiographical movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13236202/) about his becoming a spiritual leader, released in 2020.

My question: if I ask

> How does Catholicism compare the Christian teaching of love with Happy Science teaching of love?

will that be on topic for the site under `comparative-religion` even though Happy Science [has been labelled to be a New Age + Eastern mysticism hybrid cult](https://www.evangelical-times.org/articles/cults-and-other-religions/the-unhappy-truth-behind-happy-science/), not an established major religions like Islam, Judaism, Buddhism and Hinduism?

I was NOT planning to ask the question, by the way, because it's beneath the level of seriousness that Christians may want to give to this particular cult, but I'm just wondering whether it is on topic if another widespread cult that is too similar to Christianity shows up.

Comment: Evaluations at that level would seem to me to be too opinion based. We can deal with factual comparative religion questions, but analysis like that would depend too much on what the individual wants to emphasise.

Comment: The question matter may be dubious. However I would be agreeable to entertaining the idea. All would have to depend on how the question was framed. A test question would have to avoid a opinion based platform as curiousdanni explains.